# How to install django-cron on windows machine?

Tags: python, django, installation, django-cron

I'm trying to get [django-cron](https://github.com/Tivix/django-cron) to work on a winXP machine. (Wish I could use *nix).

Done

```
pip install django-cron
```

Added `django_cron` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`.

Then from windows console, ran below command

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

The result I got is:

```
"Not synced (use migrations):
 `- django_cron`
(use ./manage.py migrate to migrate these)"
```

OK, So as per instructions from error msg I did, `C:\ python manage.py migrate`. Result is as follow:

```
Running migrations for django_cron:
- Nothing to migrate.
- Loading initial data for django_cron.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
```

Now what? What should I Google in order to figure out what's wrong with the migration?

Did I installed django-cron on the appropriate location? 
Right now it's in

```
python27\Lib\site-packages\django_cron
```

Comment: How to install djang-cron http://code.google.com/p/django-cron/wiki/Install

Comment: Thanks for the link. Well, now I know that my DB include a table for cron jobs and it's empty. I guess it implies that django_cron was successfully installed. It seems that my problem is that Django relay on the cron shell command while windows don't has it.